# Convert an int to a QString with zero padding (leading zeroes)

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I want to "stringify" a number and add zero-padding, like how `printf("%05d")` would add leading zeros if the number is less than 5 digits.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Use this:

```
QString number = QStringLiteral("%1").arg(yourNumber, 5, 10, QLatin1Char('0'));
```

5 here corresponds to 5 in `printf("%05d")`. 10 is the radix, you can put 16 to print the number in hex.

Comment: Thanks. Documentation [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#arg-10).

Comment: Very useful for creating hex color codes from integer, thanks :)

Comment: And why the string argument is `"%1"`?

Comment: @Zaibis Because it's the first argument. If there were more, they would be `%2` etc. See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg

Comment: @sashoalm how we can remove the same number of leading zero?         
ex. My hex was 1f with QString("%1").arg(yourNumber, 5, 10, QChar('0')); it became 001f. now how to do the reverse to get 1f again? thanks for the help in an advance.

Comment: Correspondent with QByteArray: QByteArray::number(yourNumber, 10).rightJustified(5, '0');

Comment: There should be a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Not sure if there's a more efficient way but you could do `QString::number(padded.toInt(), 16)` where `padded` is your string with leading zeros

Answer (score 60):

QString QString::rightJustified ( int width, QChar fill = QLatin1Char( ' ' ), bool truncate = false ) const

```
int myNumber = 99;
QString result;
result = QString::number(myNumber).rightJustified(5, '0');
```

result is now 00099

Comment: thank you, I'm creating a string on the fly using += so the selected solution couldn't be used.

Comment: Better but still creates a temporary string :/

Answer (score 20):

**The Short Example:**

```
int myNumber = 9;

//Arg1: the number
//Arg2: how many 0 you want?
//Arg3: The base (10 - decimal, 16 hexadecimal - if you don't understand, choose 10)
//      It seems like only decimal can support negative numbers.
QString number = QString("%1").arg(myNumber, 2, 10, QChar('0')); 

Output will be: 09
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
QString s = s.sprintf("%08X",yournumber);
```

---

EDIT:
According to the docs at  http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#sprintf:

**Warning**: We do not recommend using QString::sprintf() in new Qt code. Instead, consider using QTextStream or arg(), both of which support Unicode strings seamlessly and are type-safe. Here's an example that uses QTextStream:

```
QString result;
QTextStream(&result) << "pi = " << 3.14;
// result == "pi = 3.14"
```

Read the other docs for features missing from this method.

Comment: nice, not marking as the best fix, as the currently marked answer is more flexible. But nice to know! (upvoting)

Answer (score -1):

I was trying this (which does work, but cumbersome).

```
QString s;
s.setNum(n,base);
s = s.toUpper();
presision -= s.length();
while(presision>0){
    s.prepend('0');
    presision--;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I use a technique since VB 5

```
QString theStr=QString("0000%1").arg(theNumber).right(4);
```

Comment: A lot of memcpy() and a log of wasted memory/cpu. If you are using Qt/C++ you want performance (that said, I saw this trick using in JS, and it's a good hack on that platform).

Comment: Don't give up!!