# Format a Number to a specific QString format

Tags: c++, qt, string-formatting, qstring

I have a question about formatting a decimal number to a certain QString format.  Basically, I have an input box in my program that can take any values.  I want it to translate the value in this box to the format "+05.30" (based on the value).  The value will be limited to +/-99.99.

Some examples include:

.2 --> +00.02

-1.5 --> -01.50

9.9 --> +09.90

I'm thinking of using a converter like this, but it will have some obvious issues (no leading 0, no leading + sign).

```
QString temp = QString::number(ui.m_txtPreX1->text().toDouble(), 'f', 2);
```

This question had some similarities, but doesn't tie together both front and back end padding.

[Convert an int to a QString with zero padding (leading zeroes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618414/qstringnumber-zero-padding)

Any ideas of how to approach this problem?  Your help is appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with any QString method alone (either [number](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#number) or [arg](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg)). Of course you could add zeros and signs manually, but I would use the good old sprintf:

```
double value = 1.5;
QString text;
text.sprintf("%+06.2f", value);
```

**Edit:** Simplified the code according to alexisdm's comment.

**Edit:** This method has been removed. Since Qt 5.5, the replacement is [QString::asprintf](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#asprintf).

Comment: Apparently, there is a [QString::sprintf](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#sprintf) too.

Comment: Thanks, I made some changes to the answer.

Comment: While perhaps obvious, just to point it out, you can create a temp anonymous QString and use this function inline e.g. `QString().sprintf(...)`.  That can be handy when swapping this for the static, more straight forward, `QString::number(...) ` function.

Comment: `QString().sprintf(...)` is sadly deprecated. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring-obsolete.html#sprintf

Answer (score 14):

You just have to add the sign manually:

```
QString("%1%2").arg(x < 0 ? '-' : '+').arg(qFabs(x),5,'f',2,'0');
```

---

**Edit**: The worst thing is that there is actually an internal function, `QLocalePrivate:doubleToString` that supports the forced sign and the padding at both end as the same time but it is only used with these options in `QString::sprintf`, and not:

- `QTextStream` and its `<<` operator, which can force the sign to show, but not the width or
- `QString::arg`, which can force the width but not the sign.

But for `QTextStream` that might be a bug.

Comment: I think I like this more than my own answer.