# Printing a double with plus or minus sign with a QString

Tags: c++, qt

I want to print a double with a QString.

Example if the double is -45, it has to print -045.0, if the value is +45 it has to print +045.0.

I tried using `sprintf` using the format `"%05.1f"` but when the double changes value I get printed : +-45.0.

My function:

```
Function(double value)
{

QString string;


 if (value > 0)
    {
        string.sprintf("+%05.1f", value);
    }else
{
string.sprintf("%05.1f", value);
}

 }
```

Comment: How did you get +-24.0? What was the value then?

Comment: The second answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234824/format-a-number-to-a-specific-qstring-format) shows a way to achieve that without using a deprecated function. It's not pretty though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format to display the '+' sign in `printf` is `%+...`

So your function would be:

```
void Function(double value)
{
  QString string;
  string.sprintf("%+06.1f", value);
 }
```